# What is that in youtube API

Tags: youtube

I got this `xml` from my YouTube API.

[image: asdf]

What is the meaning of the highlighted date? Is it the date when the user last logged in?

Comment: It says updated. Isn't it clear?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is when the video was last updated. I don't think it has to do with the user logging in.